# How do I remote backup while waking up my computer from sleep?

Tags: time-machine, remote-control, backup

I am backing up remotely from a Macbook Pro to an external backup drive on a PowerMac G5 via Time Machine and AFP. When the G5 goes to sleep, the Macbook Pro can't back up because the drive is made unavailable. How do I get the G5 to wake up while the Macbook Pro is backing up, and to go to sleep after the Macbook Pro is done backing up?

The MacBookPro is on Snow Leopard and the G5 (Early 2005) is running Leopard so I can't just use the normal [sleep proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Sleep_Proxy_Service_%28Bonjour_Sleep_Proxy%29) / [Wake On Demand](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774) or have an airport do the waking up whenever Time Machine tries to connect to the AFP share.

Comment: What os on the G5 and what model (early 2006) - there might be network wake support that is easily scriptable

Comment: Here is the model:http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/powermac_g5/stats/powermac_g5_2.0_dp_pci.html and it is running 10.5.8

Comment: Excellent - the manual is less helpful - but WOL is the best option for waking it. The hard nut is going to be getting the notification of Time Machine early enough to schedule the wake a minute or so early to allow the share to be ready. Also 10.5 on the MBP?

Comment: MBP: 10.6.8, and what is WOL?

Comment: WakeOnLan is a general acronym. If you had an airport extreme or express - you could use the sleep proxy service - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Sleep_Proxy_Service_(Bonjour_Sleep_Proxy) by upgrading the G5 to 10.6

Comment: Oh!! I'm sorry! And the G5 is PPC, so it can't be upgraded to 10.6.

Comment: @daviesgeek let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1024/discussion-between-bmike-and-daviesgeek)

Comment: @bmike I am so sorry I didn't see your message about continuing in chat. I will be in the chat room.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cron, or use the energy saver > schedules to wake your power G5 up.

This post might help you as well [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/14836/crontab-to-wake-osx-from-sleep) this other post might also help you, ont the [apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774) website.

Comment: Yeah...what I'm looking for is a way to wake up the G5 from the Macbook Pro when Time Machine is starting to backup.

Comment: I checked and I do have "Wake for Ethernet Administrator Access" on (the second post you recommended).

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: You could use wake on lan, but I don't have any other ideas yet.  I found this [link](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2002061709450594)

Comment: I didn't try WakeOnLan. I don't have the Developer tools installed, and I don't have the disk space right now.

Comment: You can run the Xcode installer to place the apps on an external drive. It will save you from finding an open source WOL client or needing an Airport that will wake up newer macs (I think that is SL and Lion only) when it detects a request for any of the sharing services.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to making sure that your G5 is backed up regularly is to disable its going to sleep. In System Preferences, under Energy Saver, you can set the G5 to never go to sleep, and you can un-check the option "Put the hard disk(s) to sleep when possible". This will increase the energy usage of your computer, for sure, but if regular backups are more important, I suggest you consider this solution.

Comment: Yeah...the G5 is a somewhat quirky computer, so it needs to go to sleep when possible.

Comment: On the plus side - it's still running and saving you from needing another backup server :-)